# How to document all exceptions a function might throw?

Tags: c++, exception, documentation, doxygen

If you have a public function which may throw an exception which uses other (private or public) helper functions which can also throw exceptions I think you should document what exceptions the public function can throw *and this includes exceptions thrown by the helper functions*.

Something like this (using Doxygen):

```
/** 
 * @throw Exception ...
 * @throw ExceptionThrownByHelper ...
 * @throw ExceptionThrownByHelpersHelper ...
 */
void theFunction() 
{ 
    helperWhichMayThrowException();
}
```

and `helperWhichMayThrowException()` also calls other functions which may throw exceptions.

To do this you can:

1. recursively follow all functions `theFunction()` calls and look for exceptions thown by that function. This is a lot of work and you might forget to document an exception somewhere when you add an exception to a helper.
2. catch all exceptions thrown by helpers in `theFunction()` and convert them so you are sure only the exceptions you specify are thrown. But then why use exceptions?
3. do not worry about exceptions thrown by helper functions but then you can not unittest all exceptions because you do not know which exceptions can be thrown by the public function
4. have some tool which (semi)automatically lists all exceptions thrown by helpers etc. I looked in the documentation of Doxygen but did not find a way to do this.

I would like to use option 4 but I have not found a good solution yet, maybe it is doable with Doxygen? Or maybe I just want to document to much???

**edit:** Maybe its not really clear but I am looking for an easy way to document all exceptions (preferably using Doxygen) a function might throw without manually checking all helper functions. An easy way includes 'do not document all exceptions' or 'catch and transform all exceptions in `theFunction()`'

Comment: Frequently it makes sense to assume that a certain exception could be thrown, but also to assume that it won't be thrown.  For example, consider `std::bad_alloc`.  You should always assume that it could be thrown by many operations, for example dynamic allocation or container operations, and you should code defensively using RAII.  However, that doesn't mean that you need to go put handlers in all over the place for it, because in most applications it is highly unlikely that you'll ever see it and when it does occur it is unlikely that you can recover from it without a lot of trouble.

Comment: @James McNellis: Ok, for some exceptions this makes sense, but whhat about a NoPermission exception thrown by some helper?

Comment: Why do you want to document exceptions? It make all the idea of exceptions useless. Read also why exception-specifications are useless.

Comment: You should define the behavior of your function with respect of the inputs, and if that means that some helper function exceptions have to be documented that is fine. Note that exceptions that are thrown because some invariant in the function is violated might not need to be documented --in fact it would be better to `assert` before calling other code that could throw.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I agree with @rve in documenting exceptions. Correctness of the rest of the program depends on the system handling those exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came up with the following manual solution. Basically I just copy the `@throw` documentation  from members I call. It would be nice if Doxygen had a `@copythrows` similar to `@copydoc`, but the following will work:

```
class A {
    public:
        /** @defgroup A_foo_throws
         *
         * @throws FooException
         */

        /** 
         * @brief Do something.
         *
         * @copydetails A_foo_throws
         */
        void foo();
};

class B {
    public:
        // This group contains all exceptions thrown by B::bar()
        // Since B::bar() calls A::foo(), we also copy the exceptions
        // thrown by A::foo().

        /** @defgroup B_bar_throws
         *
         * @copydetails A_foo_throws
         * @throws BarException
         */

        /**
         * @brief Do something else.
         *
         * @copydetails B_bar_throws
         */
        void bar();
};
```

Then in the `Doxyfile` configuration file add `*_throws` to `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS`. This makes sure these groups do not show up as modules.

Then `B::bar()` results in this documentation:

> **void B::bar()**
>    Do something else.
>
> **Exceptions:**
>      FooException 
>    **Exceptions:**
>      BarException

Comment: Hum, I'm not sure about this one. If `B::bar()` calls fifty other methods, does that means you'll have to copy all fifty `@defgroup`. Plus, if two or more of the called methods call by themselves the same method, I wonder whether this method's exception would appear twice or not.

Comment: I am not saying this is the best solution. I wish there is a better solution (something like the checked exceptions of Java) or Doxygen automatically figuring out which exceptions a method might throw.

Answer (score 17):

Fundamentally, what you ask is impossible in virtually every real-world situation.

There are two parts to documenting thrown exceptions.

1) The easy bit. Document the exceptions that are directly thrown in your method. You can do this by hand, but it's pretty laborious and if you fail to keep the docs in sync wiht the code the documentation becomes misleading (potentially worse than having no documentation at all, as you can only really trust documentation that you're sure is 100% accurate). My [AtomineerUtils](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) add-in makes this much easier to achieve, as it keeps the code and doc comments in sync with a minimum of effort.

2) The impossible bit. Document all exceptions that might "pass through" your method. This means recursing through the entire subtree of methods called by your method to see what they might throw. Why is it impossible? Well, in the simplest cases you will be statically binding to known methods, and can therefore scan them to see what they throw - moderately easy. But the majority of cases ultimately call dynamically bound methods (e.g. virtual methods, reflected or COM interfaces, external library methods in dlls, operating system APIs, etc) for which you cannot definitively work out what might be thrown (as you won't know what is called until you actually run the program on the end-user's PC - every PC is different, and the code executed on (e.g.) WinXP and Win7 could be quite different. Or imagine you call a virtual method and then somebody adds a plug-in to your program that overrides the method and throws a new type of exception). The only way to reliably handle this situation is to catch all exceptions in your method, and then re-throw specific ones that can then be documented precisely - if you can't do this, then documentation of exceptions is pretty much restricted to "commonly thrown and typically expected exceptions" in your method, leaving "exceptional errors" to be left largely undocumented and simply passed up to a higher level unhandled-exception catch blocks. (It is this horrible "undefined" behaviour of exceptions that often leads to the necessity of using catch(...) - academically it is "evil", but if you want your program to be bullet proof, you sometimes have to use catch-alls to be sure that unexpected situations don't assassinate your application).

Comment: I agree with the first part and I was hoping there is a way to automate manually documenting every exception. You are right about the 2nd part, I did not considered dynamically bound methods when asking my question. So basically to make your class bullet proof, you must add a catch all to make sure no unexpected exceptions occur?

Comment: @rve: re bullet-proof: If you can handle any exception without knowing what it actually is (imagine reading a user preference. If this fails for any reason, your design is to use a default value. So if any exception occurs you just return the default), then a catch all is a good idea. But if you can't handle the exception (imagine loading a critical file from disk but your code can't continue unless that file is loaded), then a catch all makes no sense: How do you handle a situation that you can't handle, especially as you won't know at compile time what the unhandled exception might be?

Comment: ... so it is really down to each individual case. Should you (can you) handle the exception (even if you don't know what it is), or should you pass the exception up to your caller and hope someone else knows how to deal with it? Therein lies the biggest design headache with exceptions - if you assume it's "somebody elses problem" then it often becomes an unhandled exception that ultimately takes out your entire application (the user sees a crash/fatal error and usually loses their unsaved data). Or, if you add catch alls, you may suppress the symptoms of bugs, making debugging difficult.

Comment: ..so there really is no universal "right" answer - it has to be examined on a case by case basis.

Comment: @Jason Williams: re pass the exception: I agree, but if you do not document which exceptions you pass then they are never caught because the client just does not know what exceptions there might be and those exceptions can never be tested because it is unknown what might be thrown.

Comment: @rve: Exactly. This is one of the key elements in the exception design. In the old days we used return codes, and a programmer who ignored a return code left themselves open to "undefined behaviour" (anything from the program running fine, to being a bit wobbly, or possibly crashing). On the other hand, failing to handle an exception leads to a much more clearly defined behaviour - but it's *always* fatal, whch means you have to be much more careful with exceptions than return codes. (Which is ultimately the main argument that convinces me that exceptions are better than return codes)

Comment: I think the only way to track all thrown exceptions would be to have them be part of method / function signatures, as it is done in Java. Then an overridden method could not throw an unexpected exception, because this would involve changing the method signature.